# Primefaces: how can make sticky for menubar in primefaces 3.5

Tags: layout, primefaces, sticky, menubar

There is no sticky in Primefaces 3,5. I need to create custom sticky for menubar. Thank you.

Comment: client-side it is all html, css and javascript. So search for a solution in that direction... https://www.google.nl/search?q=how+can+I+make+a+div+sticky+in+html

Comment: You can answer the question yourself with code... please do

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.fixedElement {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 97%;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
</style>
```

*
*
*
*
*
*
*

```
<p:toolbar styleClass="fixedElement" >          
    <p:toolbarGroup align="left" >
        <p:menubar  model="#{xxxxxx.menuModel}" style="padding-bottom:2px !important ;padding-top:2px !important; height:20px; font-size:15px;"/>
        <br/>
    </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```